# How to hide revisions tab in quiz module?

Tags: quiz

I am using quiz module in one of my project.

The module seems to be excellent and it satisfies all my need.. thanks to the development team... http://drupal.org/project/quiz

In the mean time i need to do one additional task. And i am struggling  with it..

**There is a tab called "Revisions" which will be enabled when some updates are done.**

According to my criteria the **"Revisions" tab should be hidden always**... Is there any way to do this...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is provided by the Diff module: Disable the new check-box on workflow settings, "Enable revisions page."

Answer (score 1):

use the [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) function to disable the  tab:

```
function {MODULENAME}_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['player/score']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
}
```